# PDF response to AJAX won't display

Tags: ajax, django, pdf, reportlab

I'm using reportlab on a django site to create and return PDFs.  Until now, this has been limited to a single 'Reports' page, but I'm attempting to extend the places it's used.  I've created an ajax call that returns a proper response, but the dialog to save/view the PDF never shows up, instead, the page refreshes.  I'm guessing this is because I don't have a success function for my ajax call, but I'm not sure what it should be.

JS:

```
function get_report(){
  $.ajax({
    url: '{{root_url}}/timecard/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'emp_id':employee_id},
    dataType: 'html',
  });
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="id_report" type="submit" value="Print" onclick="get_report()"/>
```

Django:

```
def view_timecard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = get_timecard_report(request)
        return response
```

The function get_timecard_report uses preexisting functions to construct a response that, on the original page, brings up a dialog to either open or save the PDF.  Using the Debugger, the response that's coming back looks identical to those that function properly.

I think I just need to handle this properly in the ajax success, but I'm not sure what that would be.

Comment: I can't really understand why you are trying to use ajax here. You want to press a button and get a response in the form of a PDF: that is exactly what the normal submit button would do.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are making an ajax call but not handling the response.
and you are right, the success function is missing. You just need to populate the HTML element(you could use 'frame' or 'object' html tags to embed the pdf in the html page) with the response and also handle ajax errors.

```
ajax({
 url: '{{root_url}}/timecard/',
type: 'POST',
data: {'emp_id':employee_id},
dataType: 'html', 
success: function(response){
   if (response)
        <get document elementid and set the inner html as the PDF response using javascript>
    },
error: function(xhr,status,error){

if xhr.readyState == 0 || xhr.status == 0
  return;
else
alert("xhr status:" + xhr.status); alert("in get_report function")
}
})
```

BTW, your views code here is not clear but you need to output the PDF as an attachment.

Something like this:
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.pdf"'

[Output PDFs with django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/outputting-pdf/)